# Converting a Percentage to a Letter Grade

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to figure out all of my grades on Excel. I already have all of the percentages figured out but I cannot figure out how to convert those percentages into letter grades automatically.

For example, the range for an "A" is 100-90. I am trying to figure out how to assign a letter to a range and having it update automatically whenever the final percentage moves between those ranges.

Answer (score 2):

The VLOOKUP function would be a simple approach. Create a table of grade thresholds like this (use the cutoffs that apply in your case):

```
[D]  [E]
 0    F
75    D
80    C
90    B
95    A
```

Say this table starts in cell D1, the numeric grade you want to translate is in A2, and you want the letter grade in B2.  The formula in B2 would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,D$1:E$5,2,True)
```

You could copy this formula down column B for as many grades as you need to translate. The formula looks for the target value (A2) in the first column of the grades table, finds the largest table value that is less than than or equal to the target value, and returns the associated value in the second column of the table. The "True" tells it that the values are in ascending order and to select in this way; using “False” for this argument would look for an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

If **A1** contains a value between *100* and *0,* then:

```
=CHAR(MIN(70,74-MIN(INT(A1/10),9)))
```

will return the equivalent letter grade.

A variation on the theme for grading schemes with any grade cutoffs:

```
=CHAR(70-2*INT(A1/75)-INT(A1/80)-INT(A1/90)-INT(A1/95))
```

Substitute your grade cutoffs for the denominators (in this example, 75=D, 80=C, 90-B, and 95=A).

Comment: Feel free too keep or roll back the edit.

Comment: @fixer1234 looks good...........Let's keep the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
=IF(A10<70,"F",IF(AND(A10>69,A10<=79),"B",IF(AND(A10>79,A10<85),"B+",IF(AND(A10>85,A10<91),"A-",IF(AND(A10>92,A10<98),"A",IF(A10>98,"A+"))))))
```